# Smart gwt. How to determine when loading is complete

Tags: smartgwt, progress

I'm trying to write a progress bar or add a loading gif to my Smart Gwt application, which starts in onModuleLoad, and ends when the app is just about to display. Is there some type of event handler that can determine this? I've looked but i haven't found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noticed no one has answered this while searching for something else.
If you look at the SmartGWT showcase they have a popup that displays while the application is loading.  In my application, I coopted the mechanism there and you simply have to add this to your webapp.html:

as part of the `<head>`

```
<!--CSS for loading message at application Startup-->
<style type="text/css">
    body { overflow:hidden }
    #loading {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        position: absolute;
        left: 45%;
        top: 40%;
        padding: 2px;
        z-index: 20001;
        height: auto;
    }

    #loading a {
        color: #225588;
    }

    #loading .loadingIndicator {
        background: white;
        font: bold 13px tahoma, arial, helvetica;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0;
        height: auto;
        color: #444;
    }

    #loadingMsg {
        font: normal 10px arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

as part of the `<body>` before the script tag loading your WebApp.nocache.js:

```
<!--add loading indicator while the app is being loaded-->
<div id="loadingWrapper">
<div id="loading">
<div class="loadingIndicator">
    <!--<img src="images/pieces/48/cube_green.gif" width="32" height="32" style="margin-right:8px;float:left;vertical-align:top;"/>SmartGWT<br/>-->
    <img src="WebApp/sc/skins/EnterpriseBlue/images/loading.gif" width="16" height="16" style="margin-right:8px;float:left;vertical-align:top;"/>WebApp<br/>
    <span id="loadingMsg">Loading styles and images...</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--load skin-->
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('loadingMsg').innerHTML = 'Loading skin...';</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<"+"script src=WebApp/sc/skins/EnterpriseBlue/load_skin.js isc_version=7.1.js><"+"/script>");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('loadingMsg').innerHTML = 'Loading Application<br>Please wait...';</script>
<!--include the application JS-->
```